# Unmarshal a json with list of list objects with JAX-RS client

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, unmarshalling

How can I unmarshal this JSON response using JAX-RS client?

```
[["YES",0.47],["NO",0.0]]
```

I tried without success:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType;
....
ClientResponse response = ...;
response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<List<Object>>() {});
```

So far I can unmarshal it as `String`:

```
response.getEntity(String.class);
```